# sympy log_expand product of two undefined functions

Tags: sympy

I created two undefined functions in Sympy. When I take the `log` of the product of the two undefined functions, and I apply the `log_expand()`, I do not get the sum of the logs of the two undefined functions.

Minimal Working Example (MWE):

```
class A(Function):

    nargs = 1

    def fdiff(self, argindex=1):
        if argindex == 1:
            return -1*self.args[0]*A(self.args[0])
        else:
            raise ArgumentIndexError(self, argindex)


class B(Function):

    nargs = 1

    def fdiff(self, argindex=1):
        if argindex == 1:
            return self.args[0]*B(self.args[0])
        else:
            raise ArgumentIndexError(self, argindex)


x = Symbol('x', real=True)
expr = A(x)*B(x)
pprint(expr)                   # Outputs: A(x)⋅B(x)
pprint(log(expr))              # Outputs: log(A(x)⋅B(x))
pprint(expand_log(log(expr)))  # Outputs: log(A(x)⋅B(x))
```

The expected output in the last line is `log(A(x)) + log(B(x))` but I get `log(A(x)⋅B(x))`.

Is there an attribute or method that I need to define within each class?

Note that undefined functions in the MWE are for demonstration purposes only. The real functions are more complex, and feature `eval` class method (`@classmethod`).

Answer (score 1):

If you set the attribute `is_positive=True` for each function, they will expand. Using SymPy functions, I do this as:

```
>>> f,g=symbols('f g', cls=Function, positive=True)
>>> expand_log(log(f(x)*g(x)))
log(f(x)) + log(g(x))
```

Comment: (This is kind of kludge since we are assuming that f and g are always positive, regardless of arguments.)

Comment: Apologies for "un-accepting" this answer. I originally accepted this answer, since it seemed as if adding `positive=True` inside of my class definitions did the trick. But I was mistakenly looking at the output of a function where I manually added `log(f)` and `log(g)`. Apologies.

Comment: If you are going to write your own functions then write `is_positive = True` inside -- use the "is_" prefix.

Comment: Thanks, @smichr, that works perfectly. I wish someone would take the time to write a nice tutorial about writing your own functions in sympy.

Comment: If you look at `help(Function)` you will get some pointers and a suggestion that you look at already implemented functions. But a special tutorial would probably be good. If you want to start one it may attract other editing, too.

Comment: I've been thinking about writing up some sort of tutorial. It's just a matter of making time.